# Passing an object by reference? c++

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to create a few "devices" that can have a "battery" connected to it.
The device should be able to connect a battery to itself using **_drill.Connect(_battery);**

The battery should drain when the device is operated ( **_drill.Operate()** ) but I'm finding the value of the battery is not changing.

I've done a few tests and I think I've discovered that I'm creating a copy of the battery I'm passing into my Connect() method. I'm not really sure how pointers/ pass-by-reference works in C++ and I'm finding myself a little lost looking at examples.

My connect method;

```
void Device::Connect(Battery& battery)
{
    _battery = battery;
}
```

My operate function;

```
void Drill::Operate()
{
    cout << "VRMM! VRMM!" << endl;

    //Battery drain by 10 units
    this->getBattery().Drain(10);
}
```

Rather than explain the behaviour, I'll attach my test code and the output.

```
Battery _battery;
Drill _drill;

cout << _battery.GetCharge() << endl;
_drill.Connect(_battery);

cout << "Battery charge: " << _battery.GetCharge() << " | " << _drill.getBattery().GetCharge() << endl;
_drill.SafetyToggle();
_drill.Operate();
cout << "Battery charge: " << _battery.GetCharge() << " | " << _drill.getBattery().GetCharge() << endl;
_battery.Drain(20);
cout << "Battery charge: " << _battery.GetCharge() << " | " << _drill.getBattery().GetCharge() << endl;
_drill.getBattery().Drain(20);
cout << "Battery charge: " << _battery.GetCharge() << " | " << _drill.getBattery().GetCharge() << endl;
```

Output;

```
30
Battery charge: 30 | 30
Safety disabled.
VRMM! VRMM!
Battery Charge: 30 | 30
Battery Charge: 10 | 30
Battery Charge: 10 | 30
```

Comment: You would take a copy here `_battery = battery;` yes.

Comment: The relevant code to show would have been `getBattery`, `Drain`, and the `Device` class. is `_battery` a reference?

Comment: You don't have enough code here to know for sure, possibly your Device::_battery member variable needs to be declared as Battery& and not just Battery.  It could also be that your Battery::Drain() function isn't working properly in that class, or less likely that your Battery::GetCharge() returns the wrong member variable.

Comment: If you want to attach an external battery that you separately monitor you need to use a reference or a pointer in your class. If you want to be able to change the externally monitored battery for a different externally monitored battery then it has to be a pointer. Be smart, use a smart pointer.